# Oracle APEX 5 Mange users and developers Error

Tags: oracle, admin, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

Hi Everyone this is my first question... its taken 4 years for me not to find the answer through others questions and google.

I am new to Oracle APEX 5 and administrating ORACLE APEX 5 for our DEV, System TEST and OQ environments and the DEV and ST environments have started producing this error when I try and click on a user to configure their passwords or changed their accounts to unlocked. I am using the ADMIN account which worked last month when I went in to reset a password for a developer. The error is below (I would rather have posted a screenshot but I am unable to as its my first question)

> `Internal Error Contact your administrator. Details about this incident are available via debug id "6818".`

Can anyone tell me why this is happening and where to find the debug log or how to fix the problem?

Many thanks

Regards,
Helen.

Answer (score 3):

This is an unhandled exception.  We'd need to get the details of this exception to understand the problem better.

To find the details, you can either connect as SYS or SYSTEM (or someone granted the APEX_ADMINISTRATOR_ROLE database role) and run the following query:

select *
  from apex_debug_messages
 where page_view_id = 6818
 order by message_timestamp asc;

By the way, this was so poorly documented, I decided to author a [quick blog post](http://joelkallman.blogspot.com/2017/01/details-about-this-incident-are.html) about it. Thanks for the inspiration!

Joel

Comment: BTW the blog post is really Great thank-you for writting it!

Answer (score 2):

Thank-you for your reply

I got a few rows back from the query the one the sparked my interest is the following

ORA-01841: (full) year must be between -4713 and +9999, and not be 0

I updated the admin password in previous months to not expire as this is not needed.. The password still expires though even with this set to no. So I entered 99999 as a way to bypass this. I just change the days to within the range requested above and the page now displays. Very silly mistake on my side in the end! Thank-you for the info as it is a great help to know where these DE-BUG ID's are stored